# How to check certificate revocation status in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicepointmanager

The certificate should be revoked if exists in the revocation list. There is an option in .net by which you'll be able to check the certificate revocation. I need to explore my certificate in the revocation list and revoke it, it exists in the revocation list. Therefore, I use the below one-line code to do that:

```
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
```

The problem is that the above code does not work properly. I mean certificate revocation will never be checked. For example, If I revoke the certificate manually certificate is still working. Is there any help?

Comment: "*doesn't work properly*" meaning what?

Comment: @derpirscher It means does not work at all. If I revoke the certificate manually it won't be revoked.

Comment: ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList affects the verification behavior for the whole application. Can you check if my answer below is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/88814 - in recent versions of .NET, HttpClient does not check the global `ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList` property - it uses the one on the `HttpClientHandler` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use X509Certificate2.Verify as described here:

[X509Certificate2.Verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?view=net-6.0)

You can load your certificate and verify it by calling the verify method.